# Error: The certificate cannot be dropped because one or more entities are either signed or encrypted using it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, encryption, certificate

SQL Server 2008r2

I'm trying to drop a certificate I've created but i get the following error

> The certificate cannot be dropped because one or more entities are
>   either signed or encrypted using it

Using this [query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127027/find-signed-procedures-functions-triggers-assemblies-and-by-which-certificate/127028#127028) I've identified the entities in question

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(so.[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName],
       so.[name] AS [ObjectName],
       so.[type_desc] AS [ObjectType],
       ---
       scp.crypt_type_desc AS [SignatureType],
       ISNULL(sc.[name], sak.[name]) AS [CertOrAsymKeyName],
       ---
       scp.thumbprint
FROM sys.crypt_properties scp
INNER JOIN sys.objects so
        ON so.[object_id] = scp.[major_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.certificates sc
        ON sc.thumbprint = scp.thumbprint
LEFT JOIN sys.asymmetric_keys sak
        ON sak.thumbprint = scp.thumbprint
WHERE   so.[type] <> 'U'
AND ISNULL(sc.[name], sak.[name]) = 'Certificate_name'
ORDER BY [SchemaName], [ObjectType], [ObjectName], [CertOrAsymKeyName];
```

[image]

but when I try to drop the SIGNATUREs with the following statement:

```
DROP SIGNATURE FROM OBJECT::dbo.sp_sqlagent_notify BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_name
```

I get them following error.

> A signature by certificate 'Certificate_name' does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your query it seems there is a type.

Comment: I've added the query to the question

Comment: `AND ISNULL(sc.[name], sak.[name]) = 'Certificate_name'` what is this?

Comment: limiting the query to find the entities signed by my certificate, "certificate_name" isnt the actual name of the certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.

I should be using

```
DROP COUNTER SIGNATURE FROM OBJECT::dbo.sp_sqlagent_notify BY CERTIFICATE certificate_name
```

instead of

```
DROP SIGNATURE FROM OBJECT::dbo.sp_sqlagent_notify BY certificate_name
```

Comment: You should accept this as an answer so that it won't appear in those questions for which answer is not appropriate or didn't work.